# JPQL ORDER BY clause with parameter

Tags: hibernate, orm, jpa, sql-order-by, jpql

I'm trying to write a JPQL Query with an ORDER BY clause:

```
query = "SELECT c FROM item ORDER BY c.name ASC"
```

I would like to set an "order" parameter, whose value would be either "ASC" or "DESC":

```
query = "SELECT c FROM item ORDER BY c.name :order"
```

And then in my implementation:

```
query.setParameter("order", "ASC");
```

This is when I get an Hibernate error:

```
org.hibernate.HibernateException: Errors in named queries
```

Any idea on what I'm doing wrong? Thanks!

Answer (score 25, accepted):

The "ASC" or "DESC" can't be a query parameter. You could use string concatenation instead.

```
query = "SELECT c FROM item ORDER BY c.name " + sortOrder;
```

You should validate that the contents of `sortOrder` can only be ASC or DESC and does not come directly from the user.

Comment: OK that explains a lot. Is there anyway to use a string concatenation in the declaration of a @NamedQuery ?

Answer (score 9):

If you want to use named queries here, you'd need two of them (named queries are static and you can't use ASC and DESC as parameter as pointed out by @Mark).

Comment: Or I guess I could just use a dynamic query?

Comment: @Pedro Sure. But that's won't be a @NamedQuery (I was actually answering one of your comment).

Comment: You're right. But the truth is, I have quite a few named queries that need to be sorted, so creating 2 queries for each will result in twice as much named queries. Is that a problem? Or should I use dynamic queries instead?

Comment: From a maintenance point of view, using dynamic queries will be definitely better. That's what I would do.

Answer (score 6):

Instead of writing twice a named Query containing an 'order by' clause, you can implement your DAO this way :

```
public List<MyEntity> findByAttribute(boolean desc,...){
    TypedQuery<MyEntity> q = em.createNamedQuery(...
    q.setParameter(...
    List<MyEntity> result = q.getResultList();
    if(desc){
        Collections.reverse(result );
    }
    return result;
}
```

Comment: This may not applicable if the `pagination` comes to play.

Comment: Just a note to say that it's always better to sort in the database rather than in code where it's possible.

Answer (score 1):

I suppose right way is using [ORDER BY clause of Criteria API](https://www.objectdb.com/java/jpa/query/jpql/order#ORDER_BY_in_Criteria_Queries_)

```
CriteriaBuilder cb = em.getCriteriaBuilder();
CriteriaQuery<Country> q = cb.createQuery(Country.class);
Root<Country> c = q.from(Country.class);
q.select(c);
q.orderBy(cb.asc(c.get("currency")), cb.desc(c.get("population")));
```