# how to sort the list<Date, String> in Java according to Date

Tags: java

I have some table names coming as i/p param to my method. I need to get the creationDate (date), count for each table and put it in a consolidated List)

and then Sort the list according to the creationDate.

Here is the Method:

```
public String getData(List tablename){
    Lifecycle.beginCall();
    EntityManager mgr = (EntityManager) Component.getInstance("entityManager");
    List data = new ArrayList();
    if (!tablename.isEmpty())
    {
        Iterator itr = tablename.iterator();
        while(itr.hasNext())
        {
            String element = itr.next().toString();
            Query q = mgr.createQuery("select to_date(s.creationDate), count(s)" +
                                      " from " + element + " s" +
                                      " group by to_date(creationDate)" +
                                      " order by to_date(creationDate)");
            List dataTemp = q.getResultList();

            data.addAll(dataTemp);

        }
    }
}
```

Now I have List data, e.g.:

```
({["Jan 3, 2013 12:00:00 AM",10],
  ["Feb 3, 2013 12:00:00 AM",10],
  ["Jan 1, 2013 12:00:00 AM",10],
  ..........})
```

Challenge here is i want this List to be sorted according to the date

Comment: Have you tried `Collections.sort`?

Comment: You could use order by sql command. see this: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3616224/jpql-order-by-clause-with-parameter

Comment: Unrelated to your question but important: use parameterized queries to prevent sql-injection

Answer (score 1):

have a look at [Collections.sort()](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/Collections.html#sort%28java.util.List,%20java.util.Comparator%29). all you need to do is write a class that implements a `Comparator<Date>` and provide it along with your list to be sorted.

even better, since Date is already Comparable, you can just call `Collections.sort(data)` and it will be sorted in ascending order.

EDIT: upon closer inspection your list (`data`) does not contain Date objects, its actually a List with each element being an object array of size 2 - the 1st item in the array is the table creation date and the 2nd is the row count. so you need to sort like this:

```
Collections.sort(data, new Comparator<Object> {
    @Override
    public int compare(Object o1, Object o2) {
        Object[] a1 = (Object[]) o1;
        Object[] a2 = (Object[]) o2;
        Date d1 = (Date) a1[0];
        Date d2 = (Date) a2[0];
        return d1.compareTo(d2);
    }
});
```

Comment: Thanks for your quick response.
I am calling the above method in JS using DWR functionality (class.method(list of tablenames))

I have added Collections.sort(data) to my method and ran the server
i get this error

08:50:55,989 WARN  [org.directwebremoting.dwrp.BaseCallMarshaller] (http-localhost-127.0.0.1-8080-1) --Erroring: batchId[0] message[java.lang.ClassCastException: [Ljava.lang.Object; cannot be cast to java.lang.Comparable]

Comment: are you using sort() with a comparator?

Comment: Sorry actual I am a beginner to Java
How/where exactly I need to call/add the above piece of code to my existing method

Comment: where you currently sort the list. instead of calling just Collections.sort(data), im calling the 2 argument sort() method and providing a comparator as the 2nd argument (an anonymous inner class)

Answer (score 0):

Simplest way is to do the sorting at the DB level.

Change your query to

```
       Query q = mgr.createQuery("select to_date(s.creationDate), count(s)" +
                                  " from " + element + " s" +
                                  " group by to_date(creationDate)" +
                                  " order by creationDate asc");
```

Comment: This query is run multiple times with different values for the table name.  All results are put in the same list.  You can't do it in SQL unless you combine all the queries with a UNION.

Answer (score 0):

As I see, you select from several tables. You could compose one SQL query using `UNION` to select all records by the one query. This is very similar query: [SQL Query - Using Order By in UNION](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/213851/sql-query-using-order-by-in-union).

Comment: I am using Hibernate Annotations concept and when i do that using UNION and its not working